# Store latitudes and longitudes in database for proximity/radius search using Google Maps API, .NET and SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, google-maps

What is the approach for storing the latitudes and longitudes for multiple addresses as a one time set up. I need to find the nearby stores using Google Maps and I have to get the latitudes and longitudes of all the available stores. As the data is huge and may increase or change in future, can anyone suggest an approach taking performance and maintenance into consideration.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you consider a GIS aware/spatially aware database? Many are these days, but some are specialized for GIS.  That ought to make your life easier.